# Angularjs form validation using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 tabs in my application and common save button for all these tabs and  need to validate these forms using angularjs.My requirement is I need to disable save button and  highlight the tab(s) if any tab has invallid data and enable save button only if all the forms data is valid.
Please give me some idea how to achieve this using bootstrap and angularjs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrapValidator component, in the callback option, you can update your data to enable  or disable your button